# Show and hide table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function to show or hide table

```js
function show_ticket_type(){
if ($("#TicketType").val("select-type")){
       $("#tow_way").hide()
       $("#one_way").hide()
}
else if ($("#TicketType").val("one-way")){
       $("#tow_way").hide()
       $("#one_way").show()     
}
else{
       $("#tow_way").show()
       $("#one_way").hide()     
}
```

}

and the table is

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" id="tow_way">
  <tr>
    <th width="120"> <div align="center"><strong>Airlines</strong></div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>Type</strong></div></th>    
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>From</strong></div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>To</strong></div></th>    
    <th width="80"> <div align="center"><strong>Departure</strong></div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>Returning</strong></div></th>    
  </tr>
</tbale>
<table width="100%" border="0" id="one_way">
  <tr>
    <th width="120"> <div align="center"><strong>Airlines</strong></div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>Type</strong></div></th>    
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>From</strong></div></th>
    <th width="100"> <div align="center"><strong>To</strong></div></th>    
    <th width="80"> <div align="center"><strong>Departure</strong></div></th>
  </tr>
</tbale>
```

this is select type when choose value we must call function to hide or show table

```html
<select id="TicketType" name="TicketType" onChange="show_ticket_type()">
    <option value="select-type">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="one-way">One Way</option>
    <option value="tow-way">Return</option>
</select>
```

If I select **One Way** we must hide table **tow_way** and show table **one_way** and when select **Tow way** we must we must hide table **one_way** and show table **tow_way** else we must hide tow table

Where is the error in my code?

Comment: What error message are you getting ?

Comment: you have a ton of typos in your code, from `tow-way` to `tbale`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#TicketType').change(function(){
    $("#two_way").toggle(this.value == "two-way")
    $("#one_way").toggle(this.value == "one-way")
});
```

- Fixed the type- `tow` => `two`, because tow way sounds too creepy... :)

Comment: I didn't down vote. But, is it possible to get the complete requirement (selection of 3 options) with this approach? Will be glad to know how !

Comment: @hop, it already does all the three options, but it's being done with  two conditions instead of three...

Answer (score 0):

What are you thinking you are doing here?

```
$("#TicketType").val("select-type")
```

You are trying to set the value instead of reading the value.

You should do `if($("#TicketType").val() === "select-type")`

Also, you should mind your spelling :)